# How get Uri form image saved?

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I want to save the Uri or pathc from a image saved in the internal storage for after get and put into viewImage form Picasso, but this does not work.

```
public File SaveImage(Bitmap ImageToSave) {

    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + NameOfFolder;

    String CurrentDateAndTime = getCurrentDateAndTime();
    File dir = new File(file_path);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(dir, NameOfFile + CurrentDateAndTime + ".jpg");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(file);
        AbleToSave();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        UnableToSave();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        UnableToSave();
    }

    //return file.getPath();
    //return file.getAbsolutePath();
    return file;
}
```

I save the image.

```
File file = saveImage(currentBitmap);


Picasso.get().load(file.getAbsolutePath()).into(imageView);
```

But never load the image

Note: currentBitmap Can not be used(because it is for save in Realm database and this take up to much space).

Thanks for your support.

Comment: what is `fileScan` here?

Comment: @pskink srry, error type, is the file.

Comment: so did you check that file is written correctly? can you open it on your PC box?

Comment: yes I can, that's saved correctly.